# Чтение текстового файла

Tags: файлы, java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйтса, где ошибка?
Последяя строка(и) текстового файла читается неполностью:

```
public void readFile(String filename) {
    File f=new File(filename);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = null;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            sb.append(new String(buffer,"windows-1251"));
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if(bufferedInput != null)
                bufferedInput.close();
            }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error while closing the stream : " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "windows-1251"));
```

Да, и в данном контексте `StringBuffer` лучше заменить на `StringBuilder`

Comment: Спасибо! Так всё ОК! Не понял на счёт StringBuffer - вроде его не использую.

Comment: @Sergey_New забей... И пометь ответ как принятый (галочка с левой стороны от ответа)